# Multiple Heroku apps on a single domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is "not possible", but I thought I would check one last time:

I'm migrating some Rails apps to Heroku.  The way they are organized now, URL-wise, is:

- http://example.com/site1 -- is served by app1
- http://example.com/site2 -- is served by app2

Everything I've read so far says this isn't possible on Heroku: that each application *must* have its own subdomain (e.g. site1.example.com, site2.example.com).

My client does not want to change the URL structure (and actually there may be some argument for that; I've read several sources that say that paths vs. subdomains is better for SEO).

Am I correct that this is *not* possible on Heroku?

Comment: try doing it with sub domins `site1.example.com`, `site2.example.com` and then you just have to point the difenet cnames to the proper heroku app

Comment: You could use a reverse proxy, CDN, or https://routepath.app (disclaimer: I made the latter)

Answer (score 4):

This IS possible with Heroku and Rails using Rack Reverse Proxy.  I'm currently doing it to run a Wordpress blog and knowledge base at /blog and /kb respectively.  For SEO purposes I did not want them on a subdomain.

**Rails configuration**

Add to Gemfile:

```
gem "rack-reverse-proxy", :require => "rack/reverse_proxy"
```

Now we want /blog and /blog/ to be directed to the Wordpress instance from the Rails app.

Add this to your config.ru right before you run the app:

```
use Rack::ReverseProxy do
  reverse_proxy(/^\/blog(\/.*)$/,
    'http://CHANGEME.herokuapp.com$1',
    opts = {:preserve_host => true})
end
```

In config/routes.rb add a route:

```
match "/blog" => redirect("/blog/"), via: :all
```

Original Ref: http://rywalker.com/setting-up-a-wordpress-blog-on-heroku-as-a-subdirectory-of-a-rails-app-also-hosted-on-heroku

Answer (score 3):

I’m probably late to the party, but it *is* possible. Short version of [how we did it at Pilot](https://pilot.co/blog/hosting-multiple-heroku-apps-on-a-single-domain/):

We have an additional instance running HAProxy. It’s responsible for routing requests to corresponding Heroku apps based on their URL. ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to turn your Rails apps into Rails engines:

http://pivotallabs.com/migrating-from-a-single-rails-app-to-a-suite-of-rails-engines/

And then mount each engine with the URLs you describe.

Of course, this is probably going to be tricky if your apps are very large and complex.