# Multiple Heroku apps on a single domain with different ports

Tags: meteor, heroku

We have a base domain http://test.com. This domain should serve several Heroku-Apps on different ports. How is this possible in Heroku combined with Meteor?

For example we have a JSON-API on another port than a XML-API.

I also want to use different ports for our microservices. So that we can scale them.

But I do not want the solution from [StackOverflow: Multiple Heroku apps on a single domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119164/multiple-heroku-apps-on-a-single-domain) or hosting on different sub-domains.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah this is generally a good job for a reverse proxy or CDN. It's actually why I built https://routepath.app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible. Heroku sets the port for your app, and you cannot configure it by yourself.

From Heroku documentation:

> The port to bind to is assigned by Heroku as the PORT environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Because of this and several other reasons, we moved our applications to google cloud. Works perfect with haproxy and scales also very good.