# One domain, two rails apps on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, hosting

I am building a multi-tenant Rails 5 app (will be hosted at heroku) at the moment (using apartment gem) which will have clients scoped by subdomain, e.g. client1.example.com, client2.example.com, client3.example.com. All seems pretty straight forward, but I would love to have a second Rails app for the rest of the site e.g. example.com/pricing, example.com/faq. What would be the best solution to achieve this design:

- example.com/pricing - served by Rails App 1
- example.com/faq - served by Rails App 1
- example.com/{sign_in | sign_up} - served by Rails App 2
- clientX.example.com/{projects | profiles | other stuff} - served by Rails App 2

I have a suspicion that sign in/up bit might not be possible due to same URL structure, so I might need to have an extra logic built it for it maybe under app.example.com/sign_up or even under Rails App 1. Any suggestion how to build this in a better way would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Heroku apps on a single domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119164/multiple-heroku-apps-on-a-single-domain)

Comment: 'apartment gem' - have you read https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#multiple-schemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little concerned this will be closed with "overly broad", but a simple solution here is to do `heroku domains:add www.example.com` and `heroku domains:add example.com` to Rails app 1. Then `heroku domains:add *.example.com` on Rails app 2 and to have two entirely separate apps on Heroku.

Comment: Thanks, stef! This is what I am looking for, will try it today with demo apps to see how it goes, but if that is the case - kudos to you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can mount two apps under the root directory. You might be able to achieve this if you're willing to namespace your Devise paths under a subdirectory, eg. `/session/sign_up` and `/session/sign_in`

This will require an extra app (App 3) which just runs Devise loaded and deployed under the `/sessions` subdirectory. You'll need to configure the [relative url root](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root) for this app.

This will make authentication more complex as your session authentication cookie will be under your root domain instead of your individual subdomains. You'll probably need to use the `domain: :all` or `domain: .<domain>.com` option in `initializers/session_store.rb` to share the cookie with subdomains. `secret_key_base` also needs to be identical across all your apps.

You'll also need to play with Devise's session creation to redirect to the correct subdomain for the user upon signing in. Fun fact to think about - what if the user has accounts on multiple subdomains with the same email? Devise/Warden scopes might offer a way to handle that.

On the Heroku side:

Heroku can only route requests for one domain to one app (App 1). The Rack reverse proxy posted above will allow you to route authentication requests to App 3. For individual subdomain requests to be routed to App 2, you'll need to add each subdomain to App 2 as a separate custom domain.

Comment: Hmm, ok, this kind of makes sense. Probably I will try to go for a cheeky approach and integrate signup process into App 1 (connected to the same DB as App 2) and upon successful  signup redirect user to <client>.example.com/sign_in as I believe I should be able to run example.com as standalone app while catching wildcard subdomains on App 2

Comment: Ah, looks like that should work. Appears that root domain / subdomains / wildcard subdomains can be distributed across different Heroku apps as long as they're all owned by the same user.